# Sliding Maximum window brute force method

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a large array of integers and a window of size 'w', find the current maximum in the window as the window slides through the entire array.

I have made two for loops, the first loops is working correctly but the inner loop doesn't move correctly based on different window sizes.

I tried to draw it on paper, but I still can't get a formula for the inner loop

```
int main() {

    vector<int> arr = { -4, 2, -5, 3, 6 };
    int window = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - window; i++)
    {
        int max = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + window; j++)
        {
            cout << " i = "<<i << "j = " << j << endl;

            if (max < arr[j])
                max = arr[j];
        }

        cout << max << " " << endl;

    }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't move correctly based on different window sizes".

Comment: the inner loop should move window steps. currently j is equal i+1, which is wrong, it starts at i+1. for example in the above code array, j should start with 2,3,4 for a window of 3. but for a window for 2, it should be 1,2,3,4.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, whatsoever. The shown code looks absolutely correct, based on the description in the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik consider a window of 3, and the above array is like the same in the code. The output max should be 2,3,6. While the above code, it outputs 2,3 only and doesn't calculate or count for 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is correct. It's your outer loop's that's off by 1, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arr.size() - window; i++)
```

With your array of 5 elements and the window size of 3, the last window is `array[2]` through `array[4]`. `arr.size()` is 5. `window` is 3. 5-3=2, and you need to still iterate for that window starting position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  std::vector<int> arr = { -4, 2, -5, 3, 6 };
  int window = 3;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - window + 1; i++)
  // one of your bugs is here --------------------^           
  {
      int max = 0;
      // this way, it's easier to see how the window slides
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < window; j++)
      {
          std:: cout << " i = "<<i << "j = " << j+i << std::endl;

          max=std::max(arr[i+j],max);
          // --------------^
          // i becomes the window's offset
          // j is the offset inside the window
          // using std::max eliminates a i+j twice with an if
          //  ... (and will be inlined anyway)
      }

      std::cout << max << " " << std::endl;

  }
  return 0;
}
```